# 一時はどうなることかと思った vs 一時はどうなるかと思った

Tags: grammar

> 「**一時はどうなることかと思った**けど、怪我の功名ってやつね。」

I also found the expression 一時はどうなるかと思った(「At one point [For a while] I was really worried.) in a dictionary. Are both 一時はどうなることかと思った and 一時はどうなるかと思った the same?

If not, how are they different from each other?

Comment: Yes, they're the same.